# Proof of a theorem in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have the following theorem

> If $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing and right-continuous, i.e $\lim_{y \to x^+} F(y) = F(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, with $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$. Then there is a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R})$ s.t $\mu((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a), \ \forall a<b.$

Now in the introduction of the proof it is stated that:

"We proved in the introduction to probability theory that there exists a random variable $X$with distribution function $F$. (We can take $X = Q(Y)$ with $Y \sim$ Uniform$(0,1)$ and the generalized inverse $Q$ of $F$.)"

I didn't take the introduction course that the author is referring to, can someone shed some light. As I am not familiar with the theorem referred to.

Answer (score 0):

It sort of follows from [Caratheodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem). I'll try to do a brief sketch, there are some picky details along the way. Let $$H = \{ ]a,b] \cap \Bbb R \mid a,b \in \overline{\Bbb R}, a<b\}.$$Then $H$ is a [semi-algebra](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Basic_Structures_And_Definitions/Semialgebras,_Algebras_and_%CF%83-algebras), so the algebra $\mathcal{A}(H)$ generated by $H$ consists of finite disjoint unions of elements in $H$ (this is the first detail). Then the map $$H \ni \left]a,b\right]\mapsto F(b)-F(a) \in \Bbb R$$extends to $\mathcal{A}(H)$ as a [pre-measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure), but it has to be checked that it is well-defined, that is, that it does not depend on how you write the disjoint union (second detail). Caratheodory says that this extends to a measure $\mu_F$ on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}(H)$, which is none other than $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb R}$ (third detail, easier though). This extension to $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb R}$ is unique because the pre-measure is $\sigma$-finite (this is also part of Caratheodory's theorem). Now we only have to check that $\mu_F$ is a probability measure. Using that any measure is "upward continuous", we have that $$\mu_F(\Bbb R) = \mu_F\left(\bigcup_{n \geq 0}\left]-n,n\right]\right)= \lim_{n \to +\infty} \mu_F(\left]-n,n\right]) = \lim_{n \to +\infty}F(n)-F(-n) = 1-0 = 1.$$